# match string in txt file and get the number next to it python

Tags: python, pandas

i have a directory which has around 100 txt files.

this is how my txt file looks

```
...............some text...............
('Doc accuracy ', 0.936046511627907, ' No of corrections ', 11)
http://10.x.x.1/link
...............some text...............
('FinalSpreadSheet_len', 172)
Done processing filename : file1.pdf
Status : success
...............some text...............
```

---

in this doc

```
    accuracy = 0.936046511627907
    url=         http://10.x.x.1/link
    Status : success
    filename : file1.pdf
```

i have 100 such different files.

What i am trying to do is generate excel which has the column's

```
filename    accuracy    url    status
```

for each file, it should get the details from the .txt file
and generate excel for 100 such files.

my part code(i was able to get all the files in a directory)

```
x = [f for f in os.listdir('G:/path/to/directory') if f.endswith('.txt')]
```

after that it should take each file from the list, and find the necessary values and generate an excel

Comment: So you're having a hard time trying to figure how can you extract values from a txt file? Your question isn't very clear.... Well, each file contains only one record? Only 5 lines per file?

Comment: @dot.Py  not it has much more content, but these are the valuable content i need to generate excel

Comment: ok... only one valuable record per file?

Comment: @dot.Py 4 valuable record per file, accuracy, the link, status and filename

Comment: @dot.Py can we use pandas to do this?

Comment: @dot.Py i've edited how my txt file looks, check it once

Comment: Seems quite straightforward... what have you tried that didn't work ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers i'm searching for ways to match number/text next to a string, say i've to select status whether it is success or failed, how do i check it?
once i have the column's either in pandas df or any other form , i can save it as excel

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers also the link does not have anyname attached with it, i've to create a column name 'url' , any leads on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already got a list with all files in a directory and assuming you stored the names inside a list called `filenames_list`, this code will work.

For each `filename` inside a `filename_list`, this code will:

1. `open` the file
2. `read` each line and store it in a `list` called `lines`
3. `for` each line, it will check if any of the following is present: `'Doc accuracy'`, `'http://'`, `'Done processing filename :'` or `'Status :'`
4. if any of those is present in line, for each one of this the program will behave differently.

   4.1 if it finds the term `'http://'` it'll store it in a variable called `url`;

   4.2 if it finds `'Status :'` it'll store it's value in a variable `status`, and etc...

**Code:**

```
filename_list = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt', ...]

valuable_data = []
for filename in filename_list:

    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        lines=f.readlines()

    for l in lines:
        if 'Doc accuracy' in l:
            acc = l.split(",")[1].strip()
        if 'http://' in l:
            url = l
        if 'Done processing filename :' in l:
            fname = l.split(" : ")[1]
        if 'Status :' in l:
            status = l.split(" : ")[1]

    valuable_data.append([fname, acc, url, status])

print(valuable_data)
```

**Output:**

```
[['file1.pdf', '0.936046511627907', 'http://10.x.x.1/link', 'success']]
```

**Writing to CSV using Pandas:** ([to_csv module](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html))

```
import pandas as pd

my_df = pd.DataFrame(valuable_data)
my_df.to_csv('csv_output.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: it is working for 1 file, can i automate is for all the files in a directory and it should be appended in my csv?

Comment: I've updated my answer so you can see how you can automate this proccess for a list of files... You just have to insert a list containing the filenames and "voilà".